# Estructuras de control para sacar promedio en C

Tags: c, bucle-for

Buenas tardes a todos.

Sucede que estoy iniciando la ingeniería en desarrollo de software; conozco Python a un nivel básico, sin embargo estoy llevando programación en C y me parece, comparativamente hablando, sumamente complejo.

Para el caso particular, debo crear un programa que:

a. Solicite el nombre del alumno.

b. Pida el nombre de 4 asignaturas distintas y la calificación de cada una.

c. Las calificaciones para capturar van en una escala decimal del 0 al 10, permitiendo asignar hasta 2 decimales.

d. Otorgue una beca de acuerdo con lo siguiente:

- Promedio menor a 8 no obtiene beca
- Promedio de 8 a 9 obtiene un 30% de beca
- Promedio de 9 a 10 obtiene un 50% de beca

Tengo casi todo listo en el siguiente código:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(){

    /* Variables para las materias */
    char nom[30],mat1[30], mat2[30], mat3[30], mat4[30];
    /*Variables para las calificaciones y el promedio */
    float cal1, cal2, cal3, cal4, prom;

    /*Solicitud de información del alumno, materias y calificaciones */
    printf("Ingresa el nombre del alumno: \n");
    gets (nom);

    printf("Ingresa el nombre de la primer materia: \n");
    scanf("%s",&mat1);

    printf("Ingresa la calificacion de %s: ", &mat1);
    scanf("%f",&cal1);

    printf("Ingresa el nombre de la segunda materia: \n");
    scanf("%s", &mat2);
    printf("Ingresa la calificacion de %s: ", &mat2);
    scanf("%f",&cal2);

    printf("Ingresa el nombre de la tercer materia: \n");
    scanf("%s", &mat3);
    printf("Ingresa la calificacion de %s: ", &mat3);
    scanf("%f",&cal3);

    printf("Ingresa el nombre de la cuarta materia: \n");
    scanf("%s", &mat4);
    printf("Ingresa la calificacioAn de %s: ", &mat4);
    scanf("%f",&cal4);

    system("cls");

    prom = (cal1 + cal2 +cal3 + cal4) / 4;

    if (prom < 8) {
        printf("Nombre del alumno: %s", nom);
        printf("\n Promedio: %.2f", prom);
        printf("\n Porcentaje de beca: Tu promedio no es suficiente para obtener una beca.");
        printf("\n %s", &mat1);
        printf(" %.2f:", &cal1);
    }
        if (prom > 7 && prom <10);{
            printf("Nombre del alumno: %s", nom);
            printf("\n Promedio: %.2f", prom);
            printf("\n Porcentaje de beca: ¡Felicidades! Obtuviste una beca del 30%.");
            printf("\n %s", &mat1);
            printf(" %.2f:", &cal1);
    }else {
       (prom > 9 && prom <11);
        printf("Nombre del alumno: %s", nom);
        printf("\n Promedio: %.2f", prom);
        printf("\n Porcentaje de beca: ¡Felicidades! Obtuviste una beca del 50%.");
        printf("\n %s", &mat1);
        printf(" %.2f:", &cal1);

    }
    /*printf("Tu promedio es %.2f", prom);*/


}
```

El problema es que no logro resolver un par de situaciones:

1. El programa, al finalizar la captura de datos, debe limpiar la pantalla y únicamente mostrar:

   - Nombre del alumno.
   - Promedio.
   - Porcentaje de beca.
   - Nombre de la materia 1: Calificación de la materia.
   - Nombre de la materia 2: Calificación de la materia.
   - Nombre de la materia 3: Calificación de la materia.
   - Nombre de la materia 4: Calificación de la materia.

Sin embargo, no he sido capaz de lograr que me muestre las calificaciones, pues no obstante que sí hace el cómputo de manera adecuada, cuando toca imprimir en pantalla los resultados, únicamente me muestra "0.00".

2. Se supone que debo ocupar un bloque `for`, sin embargo no he sido capaz de incluirlo toda vez que no se me ocurre de qué forma implementarlo, pues funciona bien así (a excepción, claro, de lo que señalo, pero eso estoy casi seguro que obedece más a un error de sintaxis que a la necesidad de un for).

He estado leyendo mucho, y no entiendo como hacer que funcione de la forma en que me piden. Espero que alguien pueda echarme un cable con esto, se lo agradecería infinitamente.

Saludos a todos, y gracias por leer la pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> cuando toca imprimir en pantalla los resultados, únicamente me muestra "0.00".

Tus `printf()`, imprimen la **dirección de memoria y no el valor de la variable.** Una dirección de memoria ocupa 8 bytes en memoria, mientras que el tipo `float` 4 bytes. Al formatear un elemento con un tipo que tiene menor capacidad de bytes, este reduce a 0.

```
char var = 'a';

printf("%d\n",sizeof(float)); //4
printf("%d\n",sizeof(&var)); //8
```

No imprimas la dirección de memoria de la variable, **imprime la variable:**

```
printf(" %.2f:",var);
```

---

> Se supone que debo ocupar un bloque for

Al hacer una solicitud de datos por cada variable, no tiene nada de automatización.

Puedes

- Definir un array que almacene todos los daros de un tipo necesario.
- Recolectar dichos y almacenarlos en el array, mediante un ciclo `for`.
- Acceder a cada elemento por medio de los indices del array.

---

```
char datos[4][10];

//...

for (int i = 0;i < 4;i++) {
    printf("Dato %d\n",i);
    scanf("%s",datos[i]);
}

//...
```

Obviamente este ejemplo no es específico a tu programa, la idea es que encuentres como implementarlo a tu necesidades.

Saludos.

Comment: *Una dirección de memoria ocupa 8 bytes en memoria...* Depende de la arquitectura de la máquina, si es de 32 bits, el resultado en pantalla será `4` bytes..

Comment: Muchas gracias a ambos por las respuestas. Finalmente me tocó incluir un while en lugar de un for para cumplir el requisitto de emplear una estructura de repetición, sin embargo la respuesta de @Gabitohh resolvió el problema relativo a que no se mostraban las calificaciones de mi programa.